# IntelliJ SBT - Module naming

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scala.js

What does

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1
Build #IU-145.597, built on March 29, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b132 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Scala Plugin Version: 3.0.2
```

use to determine the name of the root module?

I always thought it used the `name := "[name]"` defined inside the `build.sbt` file for the naming of the root module but my current SBT project (which uses Scala.JS `CrossProject`) falls-back/uses the parent directory name (see pictures 1 through 3).

**Is there any way I can change this behavior?**

- *Is there a master override of any sort?*
- *Is this a result of using `CrossProject`?*
- *If yes, how can create the same effect without the use of `CrossProject`?*

[image: SBT module overview]

[image: Folder structure overview]

[image: <code>build.sbt</code> snippet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue at hand is not a bug in IntelliJ, but rather a "feature" in SBT. When there is no project that uses the root path, SBT automatically creates one for you that aggregates all sub projects and names it after the parent directory. Defining a root project like this:

```
lazy val root = project in file(".").
    aggregate(cross.js, cross.jvm).
    settings(...)

lazy val cross = CrossProject("jvm", "js", file("."), FullWithSrc).
    settings(...)
```

will fix this problem and use the correct naming.

`CrossProject` only specifies two projects and creates an `unmanagedSources` entry in the settings for any shared code. The two projects that were created by `CrossProject` are accessible by `CrossProject#js` and `CrossProject#jvm`. Setting the aggregate property on the SBT project will make any commands issued for the root, trickle down to the sub projects.